# hgweb with mod_wsgi's WSGIDaemonProcess running as another user (to skip chmod/chown)

Tags: mercurial, mod-wsgi, hgweb

Is it possible to serve hgweb with mod_wsgi's WSGIDaemonProcess running as another user, so that it won't be necessary to do any chmod/chown? E.g. the repositories is under `/home/john/repositories`, while the WSGIDaemonProcess is configured with `user=john`

I tried that setup and can browse/clone/pull, but got this error when trying to push:

```
abort: HTTP Error 500: Permission denied
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found that the setup works fine if I specify both `WSGIApplicationGroup` and `WSGIProcessGroup`. Previously, I only put in the former.